# Include a header file into multiple C files

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, header-file

I am modifying the linux kernel for a device locally and I added a header file, say a.h inside /include/linux and referenced it in two C files inside the kernel directory. The header file contains a structure which has been initialised there itself. Whenever I compile the kernel, it shows me a multiple definition of 'struct_var' error. What changes should I make?

Comment: You need to ensure the initialisation only happens once (not in the header file). For a specific answer you’d need to [edit] your question to include the declarations in question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that it is only included once.

Typically, you would use

```
#ifndef UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_MAYBE_THE_FILENAME
#define UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_MAYBE_THE_FILENAME

// your file contents go here

#endif
```

That way, the second time the compiler includes this file, UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_MAYBE_THE_FILENAME is defined, so it does not define any of the bits inside.

Comment: Thanks, but I had already tried this and this hadn't worked!

Comment: That is strange.  This method has been used for over 20 years to stop multiple definitions.  We may need more information, or an example to help more.

Comment: No issues, I found out a way; thanks for your help!